# Grouping items in a vertical TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

### Current situation

This is a styled `TabControl` I'm using as a sidebar menu for my program. The grey area on the right hand is where the `TabItem`'s content would go. I've added some sample text as an example.

[image: Original menu]

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Background="{StaticResource Accent1_2}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource Accent1_1}" Background="{StaticResource Accent1_3}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="40" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" Margin="5,8,0,8" />
                <StackPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Column="1" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentStringFormat}" ContentSource="SelectedContent" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

...

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Background="White" Height="30">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentTextBlock" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="SteelBlue" FontSize="14" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ContentTextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Accent1_4}" />
            <Setter TargetName="ContentBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Accent1_1}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

### My goal

However, I'd like to group some of the items into another box, so that the control would look like this:

[image: Menu I'd like to acheive]

How can I acheive this look of the `TabControl`?

Comment: My suggestion is better you use list with in list and then you can achieve this more easily.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia Would you please explain your solution more detailed? How can I push multiple lists into my TabControl?

Comment: No. You need not to use TabControl for this. Actually take main listview in sidebar and in main listview itemtemplate take another listview.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia How would I implement the displaying of the content? If this wasn't clear from my question: The grey area on the right hand in my screenshots is where the actual content goes. The content displayed depends on the selected TabItem.

Comment: I've updated my question with more detailed screenshots. Instead of the simple gray rectangle and text, I'm using more complex `FrameworkElement`s in my actual program.

Comment: Yes, you  can achieve this by using listview with in listview. Based on selected item you can get the details and then you can show details on gray area.

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia Please post this as an answer and add some code (if this was meant as an answer), because I'm not 100 % sure about your solution. This way, I can analyze and experiment with my own program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would drop the TabControl idea completely, and just display data with a ContentPresenter

So your DataModel would have

```
public ObservableCollection<IItemBase> Items { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<IItemBase> SpecialItems { get; set; }
public IItemBase SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

And your UI would be something like

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Style="{staticResource NavBarStyle}" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
</DockPanel>
```

You might have to tinker with the exact implementation of `SelectedItem` so it binds correctly to both ListBoxes, but it shouldn't be that hard to get working if that gives you any problems.

Comment: I like this approach. I'll accept your answer, but will start implementing it in a few days when I've finished some other task.